# Processing is hanging at notary

Tags: corda

Currently, I am using Corda V3.1 and there is one issue which I could not figure out the root cause of. The behavior of the error occurs when the application processes a transaction. It is hanged at the last step in the below logs:

```
>> Verifying contractCode constraints.
>> Signing transaction with our private key.
>> Collecting signatures from counterparties.
>> Done
>> Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.
>> Requesting signature by notary service
>> Requesting signature by Notary service(hanged here)
```

I didn't make any changes, but it stopped working. From the log, I could see:

```
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:35,287Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Node for "Notary" started up and registered in 42.91 sec {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,305Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[[2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=CompanyA, L=London, C=GB], platformVersion=3, serial=1528610763747) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,336Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Previous node was identical to incoming one - doing nothing {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,336Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Done adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[[2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=CompanyA, L=London, C=GB], platformVersion=3, serial=1528610763747) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,336Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[[2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10008], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=CompanyB, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1528610765829) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,352Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Previous node was identical to incoming one - doing nothing {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,352Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Done adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[[2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10008], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=CompanyB, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1528610765829) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,352Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[[2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10002], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary, L=London, C=GB], platformVersion=3, serial=1528610765215) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:40,352Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Discarding older nodeInfo for O=Notary, L=London, C=GB {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:53,654Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:06:54,663Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:07:15,687Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:07:16,696Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:07:37,720Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-5] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:07:38,728Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:07:59,747Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-7] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:08:00,747Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-8] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:08:21,768Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-9] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-10T07:08:22,779Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-10] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to [2002:aafc:ce75:1007:34eb:f37b:e811:c350]:10005 {}
```

The last two steps are repeating again and again. The only approach to resolve it is to clean and re-deploy nodes but, for sure, that is not correct. Anyone able to help with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of Corda is this?

Comment: hi Joel, this is V3.1

Comment: What CorDapp are you running? What are you doing to trigger this error?

Answer (score 0):

So it's not clear based on your description exactly how you were running your corda nodes.

The issue is that the corda nodes are having trouble communicating with each other but it's not clear why. if it was running on localhost than this is really strange.

If you're running these in the cloud than I'd try to regenerate your node configuration or maybe take another look at the network map corda node as it's definitely gotten wonky.

It also could be that the cordapp it's trying to run is making mistakes when trying to execute on the nodes or the notary.

You may have an easier time getting this to work with some of the newer developer samples in order to determine whether corda updates solved this problem.

The most basic sample that basically always works is the yo cordapp (https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/yo-cordapp). Try running it to see if you can isolate the problem to the flows or to corda.